# How to convert this url to %20?

Tags: php, opencart

A very simple problem which might have been solved here a lot of time, but I'm not getting what I want.

I have an image url like this:

```
$image = 'http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/For Her/Believe 100ml EDP-150x150.jpg';
```

and want output in this form

```
http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/For%20Her/Believe%20100ml%20EDP-150x150.jpg
```

Yes ofcourse you will tell me I can use urlencode or rawurlencode. Believe me I've tried and still no luck.

With urlencode I get like this

```
http%3A%2F%2Fperfumepalace.arctechsolution.com%2Fimage%2Fcache%2Fdata%2Fanother%2FFor+Her%2FBelieve+100ml+EDP-150x150.jpg
```

And with rawurlencode I received output like this:

```
http%3A%2F%2Fperfumepalace.arctechsolution.com%2Fimage%2Fcache%2Fdata%2Fanother%2FFor%20Her%2FBelieve%20100ml%20EDP-150x150.jpg
```

With `str_replace` I can get exactly what I want like this:

```
str_replace('+', '%20', $image);
```

will result: `http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/For%20Her/Believe%20100ml%20EDP-150x150.jpg`

but I want to get them using urlencode or rawurlencode. But these functions encode even slash / part as well.

Is there any way to url encode only spaces in the url?

Edit: Yes i can use basename() or pathinfo to encode only part of the url. But the directory name might also contain the space character, so converting only filename is also not a possibility here.

And actually I want to know if we can use urlencode, or rawurlencode in full url without affecting the '/' of the fullurl. I don't want the regex suggestions eigher.

Note: The complication part is that 'For Her' directory section in the url path, and the level of directory is also not fixed.

Comment: @Rikesh   I hope you will read the whole post before answering.

Comment: Whats the problem with `str_replace`? Why you don't want to use it?

Comment: But why do you need only spaces to be encoded ?

Comment: @Bilal Its just like the requirement of the client you can say.

Comment: @PrasanthBendra I want them working on emails. Gmail (not tried on others) is not showing images if spaces are not replaced by %20, even + is not showing the images at gmail.

Comment: @xdazz's answer is the best way to go

Comment: You need to split up the url into parts. `urlencode` doesn't understand the structure of a url (and it would be useless for its intended purpose if it did). You need to strip off the domain and separate by slashes before urlencoding, and then recombine the result to get what you are looking for.

Comment: @anurupr I don't agree with you. That thing is already mentioned in the question's edit section.

Comment: regarding your edit: `str_replace` is not regex, btw, since seemingly nobody mentioned regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is **[rawurlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/zh/function.rawurlencode.php)**, but only encode the necessary part of your url.

Example:

```
$image = sprintf(
  'http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/%s/%s',
  rawurlencode('For Her'),
  rawurlencode('Believe 100ml EDP-150x150.jpg')
);
```

But if you still want to apply to the whole url string, you could do like below:

```
function my_url_encode($url) {
    $info = parse_url($url);
    return sprintf('%s://%s/%s', 
                   $info['scheme'], 
                   $info['host'], 
                   implode('/', array_map('rawurlencode', explode('/', $info['path']))));
}
```

Comment: Haven't I mentioned rawurlencode in the question. Please read full post before replying.

Comment: you mentioned. `but I want to get them using urlencode or rawurlencode` . i think this answer should solve your issue . you will need to encode only the the necessary part. `rawurlencode` will not take care of that part for you.

Comment: @Yegya See the example.

Comment: @Yegya where are you getting the `/image/cache/data/another/For Her/Believe 100ml EDP-150x150.jpg'` part of the image. i'm assuming that some part of the url is static ( remains constant ) . so why don't you separate the constant part of the url from the variable part of the url and put those in two variables and encode the variable part of the url using `rawurlencode`. is that possible?

Comment: @xdazz Yea that's one of the smart way of the solution. but, for your information that part is dynamic as well. The directory will never be static in this case, might be further deep level.

Comment: @Yegya See the updated, wrote a function for your dynamic level path.

Comment: @xdazz Thats more interesting solution. I've voted up for this answer. Before choosing this as answer, I would like to wait for few more answers for in case.

Answer (score 1):

`UrlEncode` should be used only when encoding a string to be used in query of the url.

So my suggestion here is for you to keep with the `str_replace('+', '%20', $image);` code, as you have the full url and not only the query part.

The other option is to parse the url, extract the path, encode it and rebuild the url, here is one example:

```
$image = 'http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/For Her/Believe 100ml EDP-150x150.jpg'

$path = parse_url($image, PHP_URL_PATH);//extract the path
$epath = rawurlencode($path);//encode it
$enc_image = 'http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/'.$epath;//build the new url
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse, we can use it, but I don't want str_replace. Its the requirement of my client.

Comment: @Yegya I updated my answer with a different solution, haven't tested it but should work

Comment: I think your modified solution will munge `/` characters in the path. no bueno.

Comment: @TimSeguine I think you are right, unfortunatelly I dont have any php environment right now to test this code... I dont think that there is a way to do this without the str_replace, unless if he split the path by / and apply the rawurlencode for each string

Comment: @fmodos Spliting the path by '/' is out of the solution since the path segment  is not fixed. It is dynamic.

Comment: @Yegya that is actually a solution and was just pointed out with a code example by xdazz user in his answer

Comment: @fmodos Voted up for your effort though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$image = 'http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/For Her/Believe 100ml EDP-150x150.jpg';
$parts = parse_url($image);
$image_path = explode('/',$parts['path']);
foreach($image_path as $key => $image_path_part){
$image_path[$key] = rawurlencode($image_path_part);
}
echo $parts['scheme']."://".$parts['host'].implode('/',$image_path);
```

**Output**: `http://perfumepalace.arctechsolution.com/image/cache/data/another/For%20Her/Believe%20100ml%20EDP-150x150.jpg`

Have a nice day!!

Comment: Simple and nice way. +1. Thanx. @xdazz's solution rocks though.

Comment: I checked his solution now. It's good except there's an extra `/` before `image` folder. So please remove that before you use it.